# Electromagnetic Induction: Winding one vs multiple?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Two options for design of a toroidal winding.  One uses a single wire of 2.65mm dia, the second option is to use 7 strands of 1mm dia wire (wired in parallel). This gives the same cross section area of wire. But, whilst current capacity would be the same, would using 7 x  1mm wires change the induction effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multicore wire has the potential to decrease the effective resistance of the coil when using alternating currents and hence increase the Q-value of the inductor.

The reason for this is that as the frequency of an alternating current is increased then the current tends to flow nearer the surface of the wire - [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) and the distribution of the current within a wire is affected by other wires close to it - [proximity effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_effect_(electromagnetism)).
Having multiple strands of insulated wire reduces these effects.

Below about $2 \, \rm MHz$ [Litz wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire) is used which is composed of multiple strands of insulated wire put together in a number of different arrangements.[enter link description here](https://www.newenglandwire.com/products/litz-wire-and-formed-cables/Litz%20Wire%20Types).